# Custom array concat with the same key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
$array1[01] = "audi||opel";
$array1[02] = "bmw||ford";
```

and the second one

```
$array2[01] = "blue||yellow";
$array2[02] = "white||red";
```

I would like to merge the two arrays and get my array in this format:

```
$array_custom[01] = "audi||opel||blue||yellow";
$array_custom[02] = "bmw||ford||white||red"";
```

How can I do that ? Thx in advance

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: The fact is that I have no idea. Maybe you can give me some idea :D and from then I will continue myself

Comment: Any reason you can't just use arrays to store 'audi','opel', etc?

Comment: How about this: `$array_custom[1] = $array1[1]. '||' .$array2[1];`!!

Comment: @Chester I edited my answer so you can keep your indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_map`:

```
$array_custom = array_map(function ($array1, $array2) { return "$array1||$array2"; }, 
                $array1, $array2);
```

If you want to keep your indexes:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $array_custom[$key] = "$value||{$array2[$key]}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array1[01] = "audi||opel";
$array1[02] = "bmw||ford";
$array2[01] = "blue||yellow";
$array2[02] = "white||red";
$array_custom[01]=array($array1[01]."||".$array2[01]);
$array_custom[02]=array($array1[02]."||".$array2[02]);
//result will be this 
array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "audi||opel||blue||yellow" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "bmw||ford||white||red" }
```

Comment: You cannot change the key. The key should remain the same

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following code is what you're looking for.

```
$arrCount = count($array1);
for($i=0;$i<=$arrCount;$i++){
    $array_custom[$i] = array_merge($array1[$i],$array2[$i]) //Or whatever your preferred way to concatenate this.
}
```